# React native: infinite panResponder pagination

Tags: react-native

I'll do my best to explain this without code, which, in my opinion will not add clarity to this question as PanResponder code is quite complicated, and i need only concept, not the code itself.

So, i've implemented pagination, something like in [this gif](http://www.nicojr.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/page-indicator.gif).
The idea is to have only 3 "pages" rendered at a time. If user goes to the next scene (swipes from right to left), app fetches one more scene from server and renders it behind currently active scene. etc.

Once user swiped to the next scene, i need to reset panResponder: the "nextScene" should appear at the default position between new `nextScene` and `prevScene` and then user will be able to swipe again.
The problem is that i don't know how to make it smooth. Right now i'm just passing new props (new `currentScene`, `nextScene`, `prevScene`) and changing `key` property of panResponder component. If a new scene contains images, they seems to be refetched each time when i'm changin `key`. That, probably, fixable by proper caching, but this makes me doubt if my approach is correct. Is there another way to make the reset of panResponder component and put the new scene into default position between new `nextScene` and `prevScene`.

Comment: I see you've posted this question a while ago? Have you been able to solve this case? I'm currently working on infinite swipe behavior and got exactly the same idea and same problems. I ended up using `FlatList` and I listen for `onScroll` events but it's not very reliable.